# Why cant i bind data to my v-model when passing data from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I would like to pass data from my parent to child component and bind data to a input field through v-model to display data from my api call in parent component. But it seems to be problem when binding to input field i get this error message:
`Unexpected mutation of "data" prop.eslintvue/no-mutating-props`

Partent Component

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent,ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios'
import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent.vue';

export default defineComponent({
    Component: { ChildComponent },
    name: 'IndexPage',
    setup() {
        return {
            fixed: ref(false),
            data: []
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            axios.get('/api/Hotel/' + 2).then((response) => {
                this.data = response.data;
                this.fixed = true,
                    console.log(this.data);
            });
        }
    },
    components: { ChildComponent }
});

</script>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
    <main>
        <q-card class="height: 500px; width: 500px">
      <q-card-section>
        <div class="text-h6">Terms of Agreement</div>
        <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-md" style="max-width: 300px">
      
    <div>
                <q-input filled v-model="data.message" label="Filled" />

    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-separator />

      <q-separator />

      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn flat label="Decline" color="primary" v-close-popup />
        <q-btn flat label="Accept" color="primary" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>

    </main>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    props:['data'],
    name: 'ChildComponent',
    setup() {
        return {
            text: ref(''),
        };
    },

});


</script>
```

I have tried this to make mounted methods in my child components like this:

```
    <div>
       <q-input filled v-model="dataIn.message" label="Filled" />

    </div>

export default defineComponent({
    props:['data'],
    name: 'ChildComponent',
    setup() {
        return {
            text: ref(''),
            dataIn:{}
        };
    },

    mounted(){
    this.dataIn = this.data
    },
});
```

It seems to work but not optimal, i lost my data when i refresh my page. Anyone have a soulution ?

Answer (score 1):

Props should be read readonly.
Your `dataIn` approach needs a watcher that will update your `dataIn` whenever your `data` props change

optionsApi:

```
export default defineComponent({
props:['data'],
name: 'ChildComponent',
data() {
   text: '',
   data: this.dataIn,
}

watcher: {
   dataIn: (newValue,oldValue){
      this.data = newValue
   }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need to emit event from child or to use computed property with getter/setter:

```js
const { ref, onMounted, watch } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = ref({})
    const getData = () => {
      items.value = ({id: 1, message: 'aaa'})
      /*axios.get('/api/Hotel/' + 2).then((response) => {
        this.data = response.data;
        this.fixed = true,
            console.log(this.data);
      });*/
    }
    onMounted(async() => await getData())
    //  react to chenges from child
    const changed = (val) => {
      items.value.message = val.message
    }
    return {
      //fixed: ref(false),
      items, changed
    };
  },
})

app.component('ChildComponent', {
  template: `
    <main>
      <q-card class="height: 500px; width: 500px">
        <q-card-section>
          <div class="text-h6">Terms of Agreement</div>
          <div class="q-pa-md">
            <div class="q-gutter-md" style="max-width: 300px">
            <div>
                                              <!--  listen to updating -->
            <q-input filled v-model="text.message" @update:model-value="change" label="Filled" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
      <q-separator />
      <q-separator />
      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn flat label="Decline" color="primary" v-close-popup />
        <q-btn flat label="Accept" color="primary" v-close-popup />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </main>
  `,
  props:['items'],
  setup(props, {emit}) {
    const text = ref(props.items)
    //  emit event with changed value
    const change = () => { emit('changed', text.value) }
    //  watch for the props changes
    watch(
      () => props.items,
      (newValue, oldValue) => {
        text.value = newValue;
      }
    );
    return {
      text, change
    };
  },
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.5.5/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="q-app">
  {{items}}
                              <!--  listen to child event  -->
  <child-component :items="items" @changed="changed"></child-component>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.5.5/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to make change to your data on your child component, you have to make it two-way binding. You should change your child code like this ( you are using custom q-input in your component and the attributes may differ a little but it is the same concept) :

```
<q-input
        :value="value"
        v-bind="$attrs"        
        v-on="$listeners"
        @input="(v) => $emit('input', v)"
      />
```

and instead of using data prop you should change it to value :

```
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String], // multiple type also defenition accepted
      default: "",
    },
}
```

then in your parent simply use child component like this :

```
<your-child-component v-model="someData" />
```